# Trouble with formatting a string that contains a date in java

Tags: java, date-formatting, date

Basically I have a string that includes a date and I am trying to have it print out a 0 infront of the months and days that only have 1 digit. so 1 would print out 01. This is the code I have written but i get an error that is saying : Exception in thread "main"java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String.

```
day = String.format("%02d", day);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `day` is an `int`

then with

```
day = String.format("%02d", day);
```

you are trying to re-assign a String to the `int`

try

```
String dayStr = String.format("%02d", day);
```

**edit**

So as `day` is already a `String` then `format("%02d", day);` will not work `d` means it is an `int`

So convert it to a `int` first

```
day = String.format("%02d", Integer.valueOf (day));
```

Comment: day is a string.. it is actually part of a larger string called date which houses the date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 2):

If I am allowed to take a step back: this may smell a bit like a design problem. You shouldn’t store your date in a string in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. You should store your date in a `LocalDate`. Of course, if the date is string input, for instance from the user, you need to accept is as such. Then convert to `LocalDate`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");
    String dateString = "1/9/2019";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
```

For formatting the day of month into two digits use another `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayOfMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
    String dayString = date.format(dayOfMonthFormatter);
    System.out.println("Day in two digits is " + dayString);
```

Output in this case is:

> Day in two digits is 01

Or to output the full date with two-digit day and two-digit month:

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    String outputString = date.format(outputDateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Output: " + outputString);
```

> Output: 01/09/2019

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).